# Java: Replace part of file without writing the entire file again

Tags: java, io

Is it possible to replace part of a files content, without rewriting the entire file to the disk.
Say that i have a very large file of several gigabytes, how to i replace the bytes from, lets say position 100 to 200 without rewriting the entire file?

As an added bonus, i need a solution that does not use any features never than java 1.4.

Comment: JAVA 1.4?!?!?!? Are these really necessary requirements?

Comment: I'm assuming having several more reasonably sized fikes isn't a possibility

Comment: I have used systems with 1.5, but this is actually crazy. Can you tell where is this going to be used?

Comment: Yep. Legacy code is very nice. And no, i can't reduce the file size. But RandomAccessFile seems right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're *positive* that you're going to be writing exactly the same number of bytes, you can use a [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) to accomplish this (available since Java 1.0). Just open the file, seek to wherever you need to be, and overwrite those bytes with whatever your new data is.

```
RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(new File("C:\\test\\huge.txt"), "rw");
f.seek(100); // Seek ahead
f.write("here is some new stuff".getBytes())
```

You can also read from the file at arbitrary points in the same fashion, in case you don't know exactly how much data you need to replace (e.g. so you can pad/truncate whatever you're writing to avoid doing something awful by accident).